# Mpi_File_iwrite fails to write; aio_write() error: Invalid argument

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, fwrite, openmpi

```
 if(my_rank==0)
    {
      sprintf(str,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n");
      MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str,strlen(str), MPI_CHAR,&request);
      a=a+strlen(str);
      sprintf(str,"<!DOCTYPE Xdmf SYSTEM \"Xdmf.dtd\" []> \n");
      MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str,strlen(str), MPI_CHAR,&request);
      a=a+strlen(str);
      sprintf(str,"<Xdmf Version=\"2.0\">\n");
      MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str,strlen(str), MPI_CHAR,&request);
      a=a+strlen(str);
   }
```

aio_write() error: Invalid argument; 
I also have an wait command before closing the file.
This error happens when I use on the cluster with openmpi/2.0.1 
on the local machine with openmpi/1.10.1 it works fine

Comment: answer 1 is complete, problem solved,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MPI_File_iwrite()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_iwrite.3.php) is a non-blocking operation. Hence, it can return right after being called and read the content of `str` centuries after having returned. Here are a couple of consequences:

- Modifying the buffer `str` right after calling `MPI_File_iwrite()` is not a good idea. Indeed, the completion of the writing operation must be checked before modifying the buffer `str`!
- Successive calls to `MPI_File_iwrite()` can lead to scrambled files: the order of writing operations may not be similar to the order of the calls...
- Overwriting the request each time `MPI_File_iwrite(...,&request)` is called is a nice way to ensure that the completion of all writing operations will never be checked...

Two solutions:

- Stick to [`MPI_File_write()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_write.3.php) or call `MPI_Wait(&request,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);` right after each call to `MPI_File_iwrite()`. That way, the order of the writting operation will be identical to the one of the calls.
- If the order of the lines does not matter, the following code might do the trick:

  ```
  if(my_rank==0)
  {
     char str[142];
     char str2[142];
     char str3[142];
     MPI_Request requests[3];
     snprintf(str,142,"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n");
     MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str,strlen(str), MPI_CHAR,&request[0]);
     a=a+strlen(str);
     snprintf(str2,142,"<!DOCTYPE Xdmf SYSTEM \"Xdmf.dtd\" []> \n");
     MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str2,strlen(str2), MPI_CHAR,&request[1]);
     a=a+strlen(str2);
     snprintf(str3,142,"<Xdmf Version=\"2.0\">\n");
     MPI_File_iwrite(fp,str3,strlen(str3), MPI_CHAR,&request[2]);
     a=a+strlen(str3);
     MPI_Waitall(3,requests,MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
  }
  ```

Lastly, the documentation of Open MPI on [`MPI_File_iwrite()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_iwrite.3.php) and [`MPI_File_write()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_File_write.3.php) states that:

> It is erroneous to call this function if MPI_MODE_SEQUENTIAL mode was specified when the file was opened.